# OOP Tkinter how to pass a value to a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm rewriting my program in OOP and I'm faced with the problem that I can't turn to graphInA and graphInB in the calBut function. How can I implement this?

```
import customtkinter as CTtk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Style


class App(CTtk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.checkNaN()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.title("График функции")
        CTtk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        
        CTtk.CTkLabel(text="Введите пределы интегрирования").grid(row=0,column=0)     
        CTtk.CTkLabel(text="до", width=50).grid(row=0,column=1)   
        CTtk.CTkLabel(text="и от", width=50).grid(row=0,column=3)        
             
        graphInA = CTtk.CTkEntry(width=50)
        graphInA.grid(row=0, column=2)
        
        graphInB = CTtk.CTkEntry(width=50)
        graphInB.grid(row=0, column=4)

        but = CTtk.CTkButton(text="Рассчитать", fg_color="black", width=50, command=self.calBut)
        but.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10)
    
    def calBut(self):
        if len(graphInA.get()) > 0 and len(graphInB.get()) > 0:
            try:
                float(graphInA.get())
                float(graphInB.get())
            except TypeError:
                messagebox.showinfo("Ошибка", "Значение не число")
            else: return 0
        else: 
            messagebox.showinfo("Ошибка", "Введите значение")
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

I wanted to use the function parameters, but I didn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. You can bind the variables you want as instance variables on `self` (i.e. the application object)

```
self.graphInA = CTtk.CTkEntry(width=50)
# Then later ...
if len(self.graphInA.get()) > 0:
  ...
```

or you can write a `lambda` that explicitly closes around the variables you want.

```
def calBut(self, graphInA, graphInB):
  ...

# Then, to bind the command ...
but = CTtk.CTkButton(
  text="Рассчитать",
  fg_color="black",
  width=50,
  command=lambda: self.calBut(graphInA, graphInB),
)
```

Comment: And you can find out in more detail how lambda works here